# MongoDB perform join with aggregate

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections `User` and `Post`.

**User**

- user_id
- region
- is_join

**Post**

- post_id
- user_id
- body
- is_block

From perspective of rdb, User:Post relationship is 1:N.

Each `user` can write multiple `post`.

For example, currently documents is inserted like this.

**User**

```
> db.user.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15e41a1b48d9417ebc28d2"), "user_id" : NumberLong(1), "region" : "US", "is_join" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15e41a1b48d9417ebc28d5"), "user_id" : NumberLong(2), "region" : "KR", "is_join" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15e41a1b48d9417ebc28d8"), "user_id" : NumberLong(3), "region" : "US", "is_join" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15e41a1b48d9417ebc28da"), "user_id" : NumberLong(4), "region" : "KR", "is_join" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15e41a1b48d9417ebc28dc"), "user_id" : NumberLong(5), "region" : "US", "is_join" : true }
```

**Post**

```
> db.post.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15e41a1b48d9417ebc28d3"), "post_id" : NumberLong(1), "user_id" : NumberLong(1), "body" : "first", "is_block" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15e41a1b48d9417ebc28d4"), "post_id" : NumberLong(4), "user_id" : NumberLong(1), "body" : "fourth", "is_block" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15e41a1b48d9417ebc28d6"), "post_id" : NumberLong(2), "user_id" : NumberLong(2), "body" : "second", "is_block" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15e41a1b48d9417ebc28d7"), "post_id" : NumberLong(3), "user_id" : NumberLong(2), "body" : "third", "is_block" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15e41a1b48d9417ebc28d9"), "post_id" : NumberLong(5), "user_id" : NumberLong(3), "body" : "fifth", "is_block" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15e41a1b48d9417ebc28db"), "post_id" : NumberLong(6), "user_id" : NumberLong(4), "body" : "sixth", "is_block" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15e41a1b48d9417ebc28dd"), "post_id" : NumberLong(7), "user_id" : NumberLong(5), "body" : "seven", "is_block" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15e41a1b48d9417ebc28de"), "post_id" : NumberLong(8), "user_id" : NumberLong(5), "body" : "eight", "is_block" : false }
```

To perform join via aggregate, there is more condition that have to apply.

1. User `region='US'`, `is_join=true`
2. Posts created by user with the result of number 1
3. Post `is_block=false`
4. Sort by `post_id`
5. (Optional) If user do not wrote any post, except it. I know it can be perform through `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays`, but I think it cause performance issue.

**Desired result**

```
{
    "posts" : [
        {
            "post_id" : NumberLong(1),
            "body" : "first",
            "is_block" : false
        },
        {
            "post_id" : NumberLong(2),
            "body" : "second",
            "is_block" : false
        },
        {
            "post_id" : NumberLong(3),
            "body" : "third",
            "is_block" : false
        },
        {
            "post_id" : NumberLong(4),
            "body" : "fourth",
            "is_block" : false
        },
        {
            "post_id" : NumberLong(8),
            "body" : "eight",
            "is_block" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

`post_id = 5` was excluded by `is_block=true`

`post_id = 6` was excluded by `is_join=false`

`post_id = 7` was excluded by `is_block=true`

And whole result is sorted by `post_id`.

I'm new at mongodb So, maybe I thinking too much in the form of a relational database.

And I don't know it can be perform on NoSQL.

Is there any way about it?

Any suggestion, very appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `Posts created by user with the result of number 1`

Comment: @ShivamMishra Post that wrote by filteted user(region=US, is_join=true)

Comment: @Hide do you need all post with condition or users posts with all above condition?

Comment: @Hide `post_id` `2` wrote by `user_id` `2` is from `region` `KR` so it should be excluded as well.

Comment: @ShivamMishra right. user_id 2 have to be excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve such result using lookup pipeline operator.

```
const region = 'US';
const is_join = true;
const is_block = false;
const query = [
    {
        $match: {
            region: region,
            is_join: is_join
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            let: { user_id: "$user_id" },
            from: 'posts',
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: ["$$user_id", "$user_id"], },
                                { $eq: ["$is_block", is_block] }
                            ]

                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $sort: {
                        post_id: 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "posts"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$posts"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "mygroup",
            posts: { 
                $push: {
                    post_id: "$posts.post_id",
                    body: "$posts.body",
                    is_block: "$posts.is_block",
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id: false
        }
    }
]
db.users.aggregate(query)
```

OUTPUT

```
{
    "posts" : [
        {
            "post_id" : 1,
            "body" : "first",
            "is_block" : false
        },
        {
            "post_id" : 4,
            "body" : "fourth",
            "is_block" : false
        },
        {
            "post_id" : 8,
            "body" : "eight",
            "is_block" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. But It doesn't show anything. output is empty.

Comment: I found some typo in your query. My collection name is `post` but in your query, `posts`. So your answer is definitely correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

To join two collection,  you can use aggregation as -

```
  User.aggregate([{
    '$match': { 'region':'US', 'is_join': true }  // match from users collection
  }, {
    $lookup: {             // it will aggregate the result from both collection
      from: 'posts',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'user_id',
      as: 'posts'
    }
  },
   {"$unwind":"$posts"},
   {$match : { "posts.is_block" : false } }, // check inside post collection
   {$sort : { "posts.post_id" : 1}},  // sort the data
 ], (err, users) => {
    if (err) return callback(err, null);

        console.log('users :', users);

  });
```

Comment: Should I have to use js statement? Because I will convert query to pymongo later.